# Accessing Algolia InstantSearch hits before tableView cellForRow containingHit method

Tags: ios, swift, algolia, instantsearch

Is it possible to access the hits from `InstantSearch` query before this
`HitsCollectionViewDataSource` method?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, containing hit: [String : Any]) -> UITableViewCell
```

I would like to filter out certain hits before presenting them in the `HitsTableWidget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more customization of your hits, you will have to do more plumbing work and will not be able to use `HitsCollectionViewDataSource`.

You should use methods that are available from `InstantSearch.shared.searcher`, in particular: `InstantSearch.shared.searcher.addResultHandler(_:)` that will help you specify a closure that will be called everytime new results arrive. What you will have to do is use those search results, filter out the hits that you want, and then manually reload the `CollectionView`.

For more info, check our guides [here](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-core-swift/guide/search.html) on using InstantSearchCore. If you have any feedback or more questions please don't hesitate!